# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am doing a project where essentially I am trying to make a music discord bot play a playlist I have created. This is in discord javascript and is using npm.

```js
exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send(`${client.emotes.error} - You're not in a voice channel !`);

    if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(`${client.emotes.error} - Please indicate the title of a song !`);
    

    message.edit('**!play hello**')

    client.player.play(message, args.join(" "), { firstResult: true });

};
```

Furthermore, I know there is no way to actually edit the message, however, I control the bot so could I used the bot id or something in order to change the variable message? Any ideas would be great thanks!

Comment: If you are not the owner/sender of the message, then that message cannot be edited.

Answer (score 0):

You may not edit a message that is not authored by the bot the parameter `message` is being exported within the arrow function of your handler that states the message/command sent by the user not the bot, to edit the bot's message you can apply the following changes:

```js
 message.channel.send(`${client.emotes.error} - Please indicate the title of a song !`).then((editthis) => {
   editthis.edit(`Looks like we have an edited message now`)
 });
```

Basically `<TextChannel>.send()` method returns a promise with the sent message object, here we defined the object as `editthis` and further we resolve the promise and edit using our `editthis` parameter we passed during resolving it (our message to be edited object).

Comment: Thanks my man really appreciate it, one question, is there a way to stop the 'looks like we have an edited message now' from printing out? Thanks so much, you are a life saver.

Comment: Just replace it within the `.edit()` method , you may mark my answer as correct if it helped :)